# Yii: обновить все записи

Tags: yii

Начал изучать Yii, возникла следующая задача:
необходимо в каждой строке таблицы, где значение столбца active = $id , поставить значение 0

Создаю в модели таблицы функцию

```
public static function resetActive($id)
{

}
```

а дальше туплю, какие функции курить?
Версия yii 1.1.

Comment: А верcия YII какая?

Comment: Версия yii 1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читаем тут  [Active Record](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.ar).
По вашему вопросу непосредственно раздел Обновление записей.

```
ВашаМодель::model()->updateAll($attributes,$condition,$params);
```

но прочитать советую все. )

Comment: Благодарю!
Получился код
::model()->updateAll(array('banner' => '0'),  'active=:active', array(':active'=> $id));